# understanding ssh: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key vs and ~/.ssh/id_rsa_key

Tags: ssh, configuration

I'm trying to understand the difference bw these two files:

1. `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`
2. `~/.ssh/id_rsa_key`

Which one's on the server side? which one on the client, connecting via ssh to a remote host?

I ask this, following this question that popped up in a quiz for [the LPIC1 exam 102](https://learning.lpi.org/en/learning-materials/102-500/110/110.3/):

> Wade’s OpenSSH private key was compromised, so he needs to create
> himself a new public/ private key pair. Using super user privileges,
> what command should he use?
>
> 1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`
> 2. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key`
> 3. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_key`
> 4. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_key`
> 5. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`

The correct answer seems to be 1. but I'd opted for 3. Why is 1. correct? how is it different than 3.?

Comment: Weird question, generating a new pair of keys for your user does *not* require "super user privileges".

Comment: To understand which key is what, read the section "AUTHENTICATION" of `man ssh`

Answer (score 0):

You can already infer from the file names that a key in `/etc` belongs to the system, while a key in `~` (or `$HOME`) belongs to a user.

If a person's user is compromised, that user creates a new key. Super user privileges are not necessary.